# Live streaming and recording on the sd card from Android camera

Tags: java, android, video-streaming, video-capture

I've seen many questions about how to record a video or how to stream it live. All the solutions use `MediaRecorder` in order to do it. However, I wanted to record video on SD card in high quality (1080p), and stream it in low quality (like 360p).

I thought about receiving raw, uncompressed data in 1080p, scaling it down, and then compressing, but I cannot see any way to do it (encoding is done by `MediaRecorder` and I cannot do anything about it)
Is such a thing even possible (recording in one quality and streaming in other)?